# Auto delete object while cycling vector

Tags: c++, boost, vector, shared-ptr

I have an std::vector of objects and i cycle it calling some methods of the object. One of them will check a particular condition and if needed will delete itsef from the vector. The point is that erasing the element invalidate the iterator and I cannot continue the loop of it. I found boost::shared_ptr and boost::weak_ptr, could these fix the problem deleting the object after calling all methods and after incremented the iterator? If so, how?

**EDIT 1**

```
class CPippo
{
public:
     void Pippo();
     void Pippo2();
}

class CPippoManager
{
public:
    void PipppManager();
    void RemovePippo(CPippo *pippo);

private:
    std::vector<CPippo*> pippoVector;
}

void CPippo::Pippo()
{
    ...

    if (condition)
    {
        pippoManager->RemovePippo(this);
    }
}

void CPippo::Pippo2()
{
    ...
}

void CPippoManager::RemovePippo(CPippo *pippo)
{
    this->pippoVector.erase(this->pippoVector.begin(), this->pippoVector.end(), pippo);
}

void CPippoManager::PipppManager()
{
    for (std::vector<CPippo*>::iterator it = this->pippoVector.begin(); it != this->pippoVector.end; ++it)
    {
        (*it)->Pippo();

        (*it)->Pippo2();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never mind what your vector contains - the deletion of managed resources can indeed be left to smart pointers, but the more pressing issue is how to manipulate the container itself.

`std::vector` indeed has very poor iterator invalidation: erasing or inserting invalidates *all* iterators from the erasee/insertee onwards, so you cannot even use the standard `earase(it++)` idiom. But neither should you, since erasing from a vector is expensive. The better solution is to use remove/erase and supply a functor that checks the condition for erasure, and then erase everything in one wash:

```
std::vector<T> v;

v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), MyPred), v.end());
```

Here `MyPred` is a predicate that implements your criterion. In C++11 this could be a handy lambda.

If your existing algorithm is too involved, perhaps you can adapt the idea of `remove` in your own algorithm and move the to-be-erased object to the back of the vector with `swap`, and return the iterator past the last good element at the end of the algorithm. Then you can have your own optional clean-up loop on the range of objects to be deleted, and then call `erase` on that range.

Answer (score 2):

As you mention calling a member function you should the [erase/remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) with `std::mem_fun_ref`

```
v.erase(std::remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), std::mem_fun_ref(&Class::function), v.end()));
```

Answer (score 2):

To safely delete elements from a `vector` you should use the [erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom).

**EDIT**: Lots of good responses posted before mine, so thought I'd add a little extra clarification on `remove` because it's not immediately obvious how it operates. The `remove` algorithm doesn't actually *remove* anything. All it does is shuffle the container such that all the elements to keep are at the beginning of the container. It then returns an iterator to the end of the kept elements (one past the last element to keep) and that's when you use `erase` to actually shorten the container. For example:

`vector v;...`
`v.erase(remove(v.begin(), v.end(), 99), v.end());`

will remove all elements in `v` with the value 99.

Comment: Considering the question, I'd suggest `remove_if()`. The element removal seems to depend on a condition other than equality.

Answer (score 1):

Use the erase-remove idiom:

```
// You can write a function, a functor or use lambda directly it is up to you!
bool condition(const vector<object>& v);
v.erase( remove_if(v.begin(), v.end(), condition), v.end() );
```

[This is a fantastic article talking about the subject of writing algorithms involving iterators](http://drdobbs.com/184401446).

Answer (score 1):

You can get a valid iterator back from erase().

```
for(... it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); it++) {
    if (condition(it))
        it = --vec.erase(it);
}
```

Of course, you should *always* use smart pointers to manage resources.

Comment: That's cool and good to know, but shouldn't the `it++` move out of the for loop, and an `++it` should move into the `else` block? Otherwise imagine you have two adjacent erasees.

Comment: @DeadMG I've edited my question with a sample code similar to what I have at the moment in my program. The point of use smart pointer was that maybe they were capable of delete the instance of CPippo after the last call to the second function if needed